# Is 500.100 error only raised by classic ASP page or also by ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have a website that contains both classic ASP and ASP.NET pages.
I have ELMAH taking care of ASP.NET errors. To take care of classic ASP errors, I was thinking of including an error page setting for 500.100 error code in IIS 7 'Error Pages' settings so a URL of '/Error.asp' gets executed when 500.100 error occurs. My question is: will this setting cause server-side errors raised in ASP.NET pages to also get redirected to /Error.asp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500.100 is raised by classic ASP only: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255650